# How can I get recognition accuracy of my trained .clf model in total percentage?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, face-recognition, estimation

I have used this code: `https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/face_recognition_knn.py` to train pre-trained faces detector on Labeled Faces in the Wild dataset. So, this is the end of my code:

```
for folder in os.listdir(path):
    i = 0
    
    for image_file in os.listdir(path + "/" + folder):
        full_file_path = os.path.join(path + "/" + folder + "/" + image_file)

        print("Looking for faces in {}".format(image_file))
        for name, (top, right, bottom, left) in predictions:
            print("- Found {} at ({}, {})".format(name, left, top))

        show_prediction_labels_on_image(os.path.join(path + "/" + folder + "/" + image_file), predictions)
```

And this is an output:

```
Looking for faces in Antonio_Banderas_0005.jpg
- Found Antonio_Banderas at (86, 86)
- Found Melanie_Griffith at (146, 22)
Looking for faces in Antonio_Banderas_0003.jpg
- Found Antonio_Banderas at (67, 80)
Looking for faces in Alan_Stonecipher_0001.jpg
- Found Alan_Stonecipher at (67, 80)
Looking for faces in Anne_ONeil_0001.jpg
- Found Anne_ONeil at (79, 80)
```

But it is neccessary for me to print a total accuracy in percentage, in this manner: "Accuracy: ???%". Please, help me!

Comment: Exactly what should be printed?  Percent accuracy for each `name`? ... each `image_file`? Where's the "truth" for each `image_file`?

Comment: The ratio of the number of photos in which a person is recognized correctly (matches the photo name in the database) to the total number of photos

Comment: This ratio is an necessary accuracy that must be got by me

Comment: So, somewhere you have "ground truth" for each `image_file`, yes?  if so, then you can ratio your correct identifications with this "ground truth", yes?  You also need to account for false positives too, I imagine.

Comment: "ground truth" is the name  of image_file, I must get this names as 1D array?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the dataset or how it's labeled.  If each jpg has only a single face and that face is identified by the file name, then your output shows 100% detection, but one false detection if Melanie Griffith is not in `Antonio_Banderas_0005.jpg`.  How do you want to account for false detections in an overall "total accuracy"?

Comment: It is a problem, because more than one man or woman can be on one photo. I don't know how to take it into account and get accuracy...